# How to make .py files depencencies without using import?

Tags: python, file, user-interface, exe

I want to make an .exe file of my project containing of 4 .py files, but when I use

`pyinstaller --onefile main.py`

command in the terminal and try to run the executable, the main file works just fine, but the program closes in on itself as soon as I try to call a function that opens another file.

In pycharm the whole app works just fine. I use `subprocess.Popen` to open these 3 other files. I noticed that importing those files into main.py makes the script work, but only once because the 3 other files contain not only functions, but also just plain code that can be run only on import, so only once. Rewriting these files to only contain functions is out of the question because that would just take too much time. So how can I compile these 4 files into one executable so it works just like in pycharm?

Comment: maybe read `PyInstaller`  documentation - escpecially [Using Spec Files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html) which shows how to add other files/resources to .exe

Answer (score 0):

Pyinstaller recursively bundles up modules from your entry module, so if `main.py` doesn't reference the other 3 modules, they will not be bundled up. You'll need to use [hidden imports](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=hidden%20import#cmdoption-hidden-import) for the other modules.